# Kakfa Listener and Consumer not invoking

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm building a simple Kafka application with a producer and a consumer. I'm sending a string through postman and pushing through the topic. The topic is receiving the message but the consumer isn't consuming it.

**ConsumerConfig.Java**

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "kafka.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String,String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
        
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String,Object> config(){
        Map<String,Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_Id");

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
        return config;
    }
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String,String> consumerFactory(){
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config());
    }
    

}
```

**CosumerService.Java**

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "kafka.enabled", havingValue = "true")
@Component
public class KafkaConsumerService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumerService.class);
    private static final String TOPIC = "Kafka_Test";

    @KafkaListener(topics = TOPIC, groupId= "group_Id")
    public void consumeOTP(String otp) {
        log.debug("The OTP Sent to Kafka is:" + otp);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I am assuming you're using spring-kafka with Spring Boot. For a simple example, with this setup you can avoid all the Bean configuration and use the DefaultBean from Spring Kafka so you can basically do the setup using the application.yml file, there's better explanation in [this post](https://dev.to/thegroo/spring-kafka-producer-and-consumer-41oc) but basically:

Producer:

```java
@Service
public class SimpleProducer {

  private KafkaTemplate<String, String> simpleProducer;

  public SimpleProducer(KafkaTemplate<String, String> simpleProducer) {
    this.simpleProducer = simpleProducer;
  }
  public void send(String message) {
    simpleProducer.send("simple-message", message);
  }
}
```

Consumer:

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class SimpleConsumer {
  @KafkaListener(id = "simple-consumer", topics = "simple-message")
  public void consumeMessage(String message) {
    log.info("Consumer got message: {}", message);
  }
}
```

Api so you can produce sending a message:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MessageApi {

  private final SimpleProducer simpleProducer;

  public MessageApi(SimpleProducer simpleProducer) {
    this.simpleProducer = simpleProducer;
  }

  @PostMapping("/message")
  public ResponseEntity<String> message(@RequestBody String message) {
    simpleProducer.send(message);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Message received: " + message);
  }
}
```

Because you're using the defaults with String as key and String as value you don't even have to add any specific configuration to the spring-boot props or yaml files.

Comment: interesting. And how spring knows where to find my Kafka brokers?

Comment: Hi, it has default configuration and because you're using the defaults you don't need to specify. In case you want to configure a different than the default value you can use the properties like these -> https://github.com/stockgeeks/spring-kafka-poison-pill/blob/master/stock-quote-consumer-avro/src/main/resources/application.yml

https://github.com/stockgeeks/spring-kafka-poison-pill/blob/master/stock-quote-producer-avro/src/main/resources/application.yml